# Wordpress submenu_page variable

Tags: php, admin, wordpress

I'm working on a wordpress plugin for a school project, but currently i'm stuck at one point. I used to have my code on a regular html/php site, not in wordpress. I generated a link with a variable which could be used on the site. How can i do this in wordpress?

My code:

//Adding the menupage:

```
add_submenu_page( null,'Bekijk Factuur', 'Bekijk Factuur', 'manage_options', 'dnh_facturen_bekijk', 'dnh_facturen_bekijk' );
```

//Creating a link to the new page (This works with a php function, which includes the page)

```
<a href='" . admin_url('admin.php?page=dnh_facturen_bekijk') . "' target='_blank'> Bekijk </a></td>";
```

//This is how i used to give a variable with a link

```
<a href='../plugins/phptopdf/bekijkFactuur.php?lidid=".urlencode($row['Lid_ID']).'
```

SOLUTION:

Thanks to Sam Aleksov,
I changed the link to this:

```
<a href='" . admin_url('admin.php?page=dnh_facturen_bekijk&lidid='.$row['Lid_ID'].'') . "' target='_blank'> Bekijk </a></td>
```

And on the dnh_facturen_bekijk page i got the variable this way:

```
$value = $_GET['lidid'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need to pass GET parameters to your plugin or theme.
If so you can pass variables to your page in exactly the same way as you did in you standalone page:

```
<a href='" . admin_url('admin.php?page=dnh_facturen_bekijk&myvar=myval') . "' target='_blank'> Bekijk </a></td>";
```

When you load the plugin or theme page (dnh_facturen_bekijk) you can lookup the variable in the global request variable or with WP's get_query_var().

The same is true for POST parameters.